# Where can I find hospital data on respiratory illness cases?

Tags: medical

I'm looking to collect as much data as possible on respiratory illness cases as a proxy for presumptive positive COVID cases. Where can I find this data?

Comment: I suspect you want to have this as ~live data. This will be hard. There are bunch of sources that have significant lag and will not be useful for you (Demographic & 
Health Survey data, DHS, e.g.). For Corona cases your best live proxy will probably be the reported numbers by john hopkins